# Netlogo, selecting a value from the combination of lists and single value

Tags: netlogo

I have two lists and a single value (in each patch). I would like to combine the single value with the list and then set a specific weights value for each interaction. For example

```
let single random 3; represent the center patch
let list1 [ 0 1 2 2 1 0 0 2 ]; represent the moore neighbors values 
let weights [0.2 0.3 0.5 0.1 0.8 0.1 0.6 0.2 0.2 ];  combination of centerpatch and neighb.
```

I would like to create a new list (list2) , in where for each combination of single and list1 get a specific weight values. For example
If single=0 and list1 =0 , then list2 will have 0.2
If single=1 and list1 =1 , then list2 will have 0.8 and so on..

I tried to use “ifelse-value” but without success.

```
let single_and_list sentence single list1 
let condition1 map [ifelse-value (? = 0 and list1 = 0  )  [0.2][?]] single_and_list 
let condition2 map [ifelse-value (? = 1 and list1 = 1  )  [0.8][?]] single_and_list
let list2 [condition1, condition2,….]
```

I will greatly appreciate any insights thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend writing an explicit reporter procedure to transform the value from the list and the single value into the weight. For instance:

```
to-report weight [ single list-val ]
  if single = 0 and list-val = 0 [ report 0.2 ]
  if single = 1 and list-val = 1 [ report 0.8 ]
  ...
  report <default-value>
end
```

Then, to get the weights, you can just do

```
let weights map [ weight single ? ] list1
```

By dividing the code up like this, it becomes much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Bryan Head's suggestion, but will add a further suggestion.  It looks as if single and list1 always contain small integers.  If that's correct, then one option is to put the values that you want to return into a list of lists.  For example, you can put lines like these in the reporter:

```
let weights [[0.2 0.3 0.5]
             [0.1 0.8 0.1]
             [0.6 0.2 0.2]]

report (item list-val (item single weights))
```

In the previous line, `single` must be 0, 1, or 2, and chooses which inner list (row) to use.  Then `list-val`--which also must be be 0, 1, or 2--chooses a number from within the list chosen by `item single weights`.  (Obviously, you can expand this pattern with more rows or longer inner lists.)